# часть кода из java в groovy синтаксис

Tags: groovy

Необходимо отобразить два статических поля и вызывать/менять их по необходимости. Вопрос касается только создания и вызова и очень важно чтобы они были статическими.
Пример:

```
class SomeClass {
    private static boolean a = true;
    private static boolean b = true;

    private someMethod() {
        a = false;
        b = false;
    }
}
```

Как этот несчастный клочок кода написать на груви подскажиет пожалуйста.

P.S. Не знаю важно ли это но сам файл без класса. В смысле просто как скрипты.

Answer (score 1):

> Почти весь Java-синтаксис— это часть Groovy. Следовательно, Groovy
>   может быть рассмотрен как надмножество Java.

© Башар Абдул-Джавад "[Groovy и Grails](https://dmkpress.com/catalog/computer/programming/java/978-5-94074-618-8/)"

Код вашего примера может быть без изменений выполнен в Groovy.